# Where does the increment value for sbrk come from when using newlib nano malloc?

Tags: memory, embedded, stm32, head, newlib

I have a target (Stm32f030R8) I am using with FreeRTOS and the newlib reentrant heap implementation (http://www.nadler.com/embedded/newlibAndFreeRTOS.html). This shim defines sbrk in addition to implementing the actual FreeRTOS memory allocation shim. The project is built with GNU ARM GCC and using --specs=nosys.specs.

For the following example, FreeRTOS has not been started yet. malloc has not been called before. The mcu is fresh off boot and has only just copied initialized data from flash into ram and configured clocks and basic peripherals.

Simply having the lib in my project, I am seeing that sbrk is being called with very large increment values for seemingly small malloc calls.

The target has 8K of memory, of which I have 0x12b8 (~4KB bytes between the start of the heap and end of ram (top of the stack).

I am seeing that if I allocate 1000 bytes with `str = (char*) malloc(1000);`, that sbrk gets called twice. First with an increment value of 0x07e8 and then again with an increment value of 0x0c60. the result being that the desired total increment count is 0x1448 (5192 bytes!) and of course this overflows not just the stack, but available ram.

What on earth is going on here? Why are these huge increment values being used by malloc for such a relatively small desired buffer allocation?

Comment: did you check that the heap has been correctly initialized ? it is typically done by the C runtime before jumping to `main `. IIRC it is done in function `__libc_init_array`

Comment: I would imagine that depends on what CRT that is used. It might not even initialize a heap, because using a heap on a Cortex M0 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin what do you mean ? Do you mean using malloc without a heap ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I mean that the CRT might not even initialize a heap/the heap. Because you shouldn't want or need a heap when coding for Cortex M0. Unless your program is too efficient or something, I guess...

Comment: OK I agree. On Corte M7 the heap is initalised in the example CRT code provided with STM32Cube but for M0 I don't remember

Comment: @Lundin lol, well, I can tell you that there is absolutely a reason to use heaps on small mcus, for  schemes where memory is allocated once and never freed. An example being FreeRTOS where you might initially allocate memory for a handful of tasks or queues and then be done and no nothing more. You could statically allocate, but there's no real tradeoff. One way or another memory is memory. It's definitely not correct to automatically assume heap == inefficient or bloated.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Yep, I do inialize the heap. with `__libc_init_array();` before jumping to main. In addition, I checked to verify that the symbols are correct for end and _estack.

Comment: @chris12892 No, you don't understand, it _is_ per definition overhead and for nothing gained. You could as well have allocated that memory statically indeed, with the difference that there is no overhead code and no segmentation for accessing static memory. And the memory you allocated for the heap is allocated no matter if you use it or not, so what did you gain? Your program must under all circumstances allocate enough memory to cover the worst use-case. You can't "save" memory like in a PC because nobody else can use the memory but your program.

Comment: Consider a farming village where every household got their own field. The purpose of their field is to provide for that household, it does nothing else. Alternatively, you could turn all fields in the village communal, and then assign random patches to families here and there depending on how large it is. Any family might be assigned any part of any field. The only difference is that there will be more far more running around and less crop yield. There will be holes where you can't plant anything meaningful. You haven't magically created more fields by "dynamically" assigning parts of them.

Comment: I've never been as hard-line as @Lundin on this question, but even I'd question the wisdom of a heap with only 4K RAM available.  The question is legitimate though, deserves an answer rather then a debate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may not possible to answer definitively, rather than just advise on debugging.  The simplest solution is to step through the allocation code to determine where and why the allocation size request is being corrupted (as it appears to be).  You will need to course to build the library from source or at least include mallocr.c in your code to override any static library implementation.

In Newlib Nano the call-stack to `_sbrk_r` is rather simple (compared to regular Newlib).  The increment is determined from the allocation size `s` in `nano_malloc()` in nano-mallocr.c as follows:

```
malloc_size_t alloc_size;
alloc_size = ALIGN_TO(s, CHUNK_ALIGN); /* size of aligned data load */
alloc_size += MALLOC_PADDING; /* padding */
alloc_size += CHUNK_OFFSET; /* size of chunk head */
alloc_size = MAX(alloc_size, MALLOC_MINCHUNK);
```

Then if a chunk of `alloc_size` is not found in the free-list (which is always the case when `free()` has not been called), then `sbrk_aligned( alloc_size )` is called which calls _`sbrk_r()`.  None of the padding, alignment or minimum allocation macros add such a large amount.

`sbrk_aligned( alloc_size )` calls `_sbrk_r` if the request is not aligned. The second call should be never be larger than `CHUNK_ALIGN` - (`sizeof(void*)`).

In you debugger you should be able to inspect the call stack or step through the call to see where parameter becomes incorrect.

Comment: IMO this question without having the complete project is not possible to answer. I do not also trust the OPs debugging skills (so I do not know if the values shown make any sense), because otherwise the first step (and the most trivial one) is to see what is calling sbrk and then debug the caller.

Comment: @0___________ Indeed, the information given is sparse and lacking evidence, such at the test code and the method of observation.

Comment: @0___________  If the question were "how can I debug this problem?", then this would be an answer.  I agree the caller may be the issue, the answer is the same - use a debugger.  I am not suggesting the Newlib Nano code is where the bug is;  but observation of how the increment is being determined is one way if discovering the cause.

Comment: This is ultimately the answer to my question. I simply asked where these values were coming from in newlib nano. I didn't ask anyone to debug my project, or else I'd have the entire thing posted with a consulting contract :). The question is simply "this is what I am seeing, where is the increment value coming from?". Thanks!

Comment: @chris12892 Well as you can see, I determined that by inspecting the code.  In fact I have never used Newlib Nano.  The point is it is open source, nothing is hidden from you.